# FadeSlideShow - Javascript target = "_blank"

Tags: javascript, show, slide, window.open

I have a slide of images on my site and im wanting there links to open in a new window...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mygallery=new fadeSlideShow({
wrapperid: "fadeshow1", //ID of blank DIV on page to house Slideshow
dimensions: [860, 500], //width/height of gallery in pixels. Should reflect dimensions        of largest image
imagearray:  [
    ["mil/aircrafthangar.jpg", "http://www.rubbmilitary.com/products/aircraft_hangars.html", "", "Rubb Military 20m Span EFASS Aircraft and Helicopter Hangar"],
    ["mil/helihangar.jpg", "http://www.rubbmilitary.com/products/helicopter_hangars.html", "", "Rubb Military 25m Span EFASS Aircraft and Helicopter Hangars"],
    ["mil/vehiclehangar.jpg", "http://www.rubbmilitary.com/products/small_aircraft_hangars.html", "", "Rubb Military 11m Span EFASS Vehicle and small Aircraft Hangars"],
    ["mil/sunshade.jpg", "http://www.rubbmilitary.com/products/aircraft_sunshades.html", "", "Rubb Military EFASS Sunshade Covering Aircraft and Helicopters"],
    ["mil/warehouse.jpg", "http://www.rubbmilitary.com/products/military_warehouse.html", "", "Rubb Military EFASS Mass Storage Warehouse"] //<--no trailing comma after very last image element!
],
displaymode: {type:'auto', pause:2500, cycles:0, wraparound:false},
persist: false, //remember last viewed slide and recall within same session?
fadeduration: 1000, //transition duration (milliseconds)
descreveal: "ondemand",
togglerid: ""
```

})

```
</script>
```

any help or advice would be great.

Thanks you

Comment: You can edit in javascript. Please check img src tag in your slide show script and there you can specify target = "_blank"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter of the image array is probably the target of hyperlink. Try this.

```
["mil/aircrafthangar.jpg",
"http://www.rubbmilitary.com/products/aircraft_hangars.html",
"_blank",
"Rubb Military 20m Span EFASS Aircraft and Helicopter Hangar"]
```

You should use "_blank" for every image in array.